# Content Provider to get UserDicationary returns nothing

Tags: java, android, dictionary, android-contentprovider

EDIT: I tried using this to add some words

```
UserDictionary.Words.addWord(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"DROIDODD",11,null,null);
```

Now the cursor contains this word , but how do i access my other words in the personal dictionay , 
Where does android store the new words we enter through keyboards ?
Is in in this datastore ,then why doesnt the dictionary content provider access those?

I am trying to get and display the words in the android user dictionary using a content resolver ,Problem is the returned cursor does not contain any values , the cursor count is 0 ,
I want get all the Words in the user dictionary and simply append it to a textVIew inside my fragment

The Fragment.java code is shown below :

```
package com.sweetapps.managephonedictionary;

import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.UserDictionary;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

    private  String details="The words in your personal dictionary are \n\n";

    public MainActivityFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.v("myLog","Inside Oncreate");
        //content provider code
        ContentResolver contentResolver= getActivity().getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();
        //get all details
        Cursor cursor=contentResolver.query(UserDictionary.Words.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,null );
       Log.v("myLog",cursor.getCount()+"");

        while (cursor.moveToNext())
        {
            details=details+cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(UserDictionary.Words.WORD));
            Log.v("myLog",cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(UserDictionary.Words.WORD)));
        }

    cursor.close();


    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        TextView textView= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.wordsTextView);
        textView.setText(details);
        return view;
    }
}
```

My output is only `The words in your personal dictionary are`

My logcat is

```
 V/myLog﹕ Inside Oncreate
 V/myLog﹕ 0
```

Where am i going wrong , I am sure my phone dictionary has quite a few words, i tried it on multiple device , still the same .
Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have similar problem on my Samsung devices, it seems that Samsung (for some reason) has overridden the user dictionary... I installed google keyboard from the play store which has an option for adding words to the dictionary, when opening the user dictionary, I find it empty and pressing add words yield no response at all, except for the system sound :).

If you are like me, trying to experiment with content providers and found that user dictionary is an easy target, it is just as simple to switch to user contacts.

First change permissions so that you have access to Contacts instead

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
```

Then change your content resolver as follows:

```
Cursor cursor = resolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
int wordColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
```

This got me going through the rest of experimentation, or exercise..

Comment: Thanks a lot , I thought I was doing something wrong , turn out to be Samsung's issue (or fault :))

Comment: I was just reading an article on "Android Fragmentation". What the author meant is that it is not only that there are that many versions or api levels developers should be concerned with, but also different manufacturers, customization, hardware and software differences :)

Answer (score 1):

First we need to check weather our personal dictionary is empty or not.

I used this to get the results:

In your phone
Find and tap Settings > Language & input > Personal dictionary > Add or the + (plus) icon. And add a word. Now try running the program or app.

The dictionary was empty, when i added some values, it returned results.

For different versions of android, [see this page.](https://support.sonymobile.com/global-en/xperiaz3compact/kb/0231018807c614a08013cec540b57006886/)

I used the above link for sony.

Similarly you can find how to add dictionary for other mobiles.